# Power failure during upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

During upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 there was a power failure.  computer boots to desktop but without tools and menus to navigate.  files that can be open cannot be closed.  sidebar menu does not exist.  there is no function of the DVD drive, the USB drive nor the internet.  Possible to open GRUB but I am not familiar with it's function.  Please help.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu in the first place if the DVD drive and USB don't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover an interrupted 12.04 upgrade from 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121865/how-to-recover-an-interrupted-12-04-upgrade-from-11-10)

Answer (score 2):

If you're at a GUI hit ALT-F2 type term and run `do-release-upgrade`. If that does not work, use CTRL-ALT-F1 and login to the terminal, then run `do-release-upgrade` to reinitiate the upgrade.

If the do-release-upgrade tells you that there is no newer version found or something of the like, then do a manual installation of the UBUNTU-DESKTOP package by typing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. That's about all I can think of at the moment that might help you. Good luck.

Comment: Installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package may work, but before doing that, running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is always worth a shot before doing anything like that. It will carry on from where dpkg left off configuring packages.