# Xubuntu 14.04 partial update hangs on boot

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, partial-upgrade

I did a partial update on my Xubuntu 14.04 desktop box.  When I boot up, it hangs at the "checking disk drive for errors," screen.  I am able to SSH into the machine, but I have no idea what to do from here.

Comment: [How to recover an interrupted 12.04 upgrade from 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/q/121865) or [Power failure during upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/q/211195) may work. I recommend [these techniques](http://askubuntu.com/a/122320) to start. If you try [installing a metapackage](http://askubuntu.com/a/211232), then after `sudo apt-get update` (run that before *any* of the above techniques, while you're connected to the Internet), instead of installing `ubuntu-desktop`, you should use `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` (as you have Xubuntu). And [this may help](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075).

Comment: Tried those solutions.  It didn't seem to work at all. I'm still stuck at the "checking disc drive for errors," screen.  I can still SSH in though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was something complety silly.  I had to remove my AMD video card.  It boots fine now using the integrated Intel Graphics.